# Flutter always needing a hot reload

Tags: flutter

I'm making an app. I'm getting data from the URL and try to show. But I need to hot reload to see.

These are my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'widgets/half_category_widget.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

var searchCat;
var baslik="Ana Sayfa";
void main() {

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData.light(),
    home: FirstApp(),

  ));
  createCategory();
  createProduct();
}

void runCat(id){
  searchCat=id+1;
  searchProds();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData.light(),
    home: CatProds(),

  ));
}
class FirstApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstAppState createState() => _FirstAppState();

}
List<Widget> menu = new List<Widget>();
Future createCategory() async{
  var url = 'https://recepabi.com/pc/getCatKafe';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  var data = (response.body).toString().split('-');
  for(var i=0;i<data.length-1;i++){
    menu.add(Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child:
        InkWell(onTap: () {
          print("ID:" + i.toString());
          runCat(i);
          baslik=data[i];
        },
            child:  Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  HalfCategory(Colors.blue, Icons.menu, data[i]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ) ,
      ),
    ));
  }
}



List<Widget> products = new List<Widget>();
List<Widget> products1 = new List<Widget>();
Future createProduct() async{
  var url = 'https://recepabi.com/pc/getProdKafe';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  var data = (response.body).toString().split('ğ');
  for(var i=0;i<data.length-1;i++){
      var prod=data[i].split("ı");
      var ad=prod[0];
      var birim=prod[1];
      var kategori=prod[2];
      var fiyat=prod[3];
      var resim=prod[4];

    var myr=Row(children: <Widget>[Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0 ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                child: Image.network(
                  resim,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0,bottom: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                ad.toUpperCase(),
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),],);
     products1.add(myr);
  }
}





class _FirstAppState extends State<FirstApp> {
  int _index = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Kafeex"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _index,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _index = index;
              if(_index==0)
                {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstApp()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                );
                }
              else if(_index==1)
              {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                );
              }
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.fastfood),
              title: new Text('Sipariş'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              title: new Text('Sepet'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children:menu
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[Expanded(
                    child: Text(baslik,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Column(
                children: products1
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CatProds extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Kafeex"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),

        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                  children:menu
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[Expanded(
                    child: Text(baslik,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Column(
                  children: searchProd
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }

}

List<Widget> searchProd = new List<Widget>();
Future searchProds() async{
  var url = 'https://recepabi.com/pc/searchProdKafe/'+searchCat.toString();
  print(url);
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  var data = (response.body).toString().split('ğ');
  for(var i=0;i<data.length-1;i++){
    var prod=data[i].split("ı");
    var ad=prod[0];
    var birim=prod[1];
    var kategori=prod[2];
    var fiyat=prod[3];
    var resim=prod[4];

    var myr2=Row(children: <Widget>[Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0 ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                child: Image.network(
                  resim,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0,bottom: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                ad.toUpperCase(),
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),],);
    searchProd.add(myr2);
    searchCat=0;
  }
}
```

For example: I get the data from URL(createCategory()). I put the data to list(menu) and try to show on the widget(_FirstAppState's widget). But first, run nothing appears. On the second run(by hot reloading) it appears.
How do I prevent this?

Comment: you can use ChangeNotifier()

Comment: didn't work but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is u r calling `createCategory();` & `createProduct();` functions in `main()` function if u change some code in those methods u need to call `main()` method again which is not possible in hot reload which only changes state & some widget

so for calling `main()` method again u need to perform hot restart

Comment: Thank you for that.